# When can chakra be seen?

Tags: naruto

The answer to [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/what-does-chakra-physically-act-like) says that chakra can only be seen in certain cases, when the person is using powerful abilities. This lines up with reactions to people seeing Chidori and being surprised that it can be see. However, there are times when chakra can be seen when it is being built up instead of being used in a jutsu.

How does this happen, if chakra only shows up when someone is using a strong ability (such as Chidori)? Or is what Naruto using in the image somehow a different type of chakra?

[image: Naruto Chakra]

Comment: i know that Naruto has 2 types of Charkra, the normal blue kind and the Red Charkra of the Nine-Tailed Fox, i'm pritty sure the Red Charkra can be seen by anyone as after the Nine-Tails was sealed it's charkra could be seen which lead to the idea of havesting it and implanting it into Sora and also people can see it form around Naruto when the Nine-Tails Viel is forming

Comment: the image you have there is during Naruto's and Haku's battle and i think that's the point where Naruto thinks Sasuke is dead and the Nine-Tails gets a little freedom so seeing Naruto's Blue Charkra may actually be it having some of the Red Charkra in it before it actually turns red

Comment: A simple example is Rasengan. Its is basically Chakra moulded into a spherical form. You can clearly see Naruto's chakra being moulded into a ball shape. So basically Chakra can be seen whenever a jutsu uses it externally, like Chidori, Rasengan, etc.

Comment: This question sort of confuses me. I feel as if this topic might pertain more to detecting chakra as opposed to just seeing it. There are specific Shinobi that are sensor types, like Karin.

Comment: The question is specifically about seeing it because of the comment about chidori being impressive because you can see the chakra seems counter to the fact that we can see it around Naruto in cases like in the picture.

Comment: The confusing part is when you show Naruto's picture and ask if his chakra is different. Technically, it is different because his enormous chakra pool is credited to the Kyuubi and this picture is showing Naruto's above-average chakra. But all of this stuff doesn't really affect the answer to the question in your title. Simply put: Chakra becomes visible when concentrated. It's really that simple and a reoccurring concept in many Animes, like DBZ. As you said yourself, chakra can be seen when being built up.

Comment: In the question, you linked powerful abilities with jutsus in order to display chakra. Here are some counter examples: Opening the 8 gates, tapping into a tailed beast's chakra, and healing. They all display chakra, but the first two aren't jutsus. While healing is a jutsu, I think it is arguable about whether it is (always) considered powerful or not.

Comment: @krikara Tailed beast/ 8gates pretty much got handled in my answer. The 8 gates actually opening more tenketsu and the tailed beast falling beyond those limits

Answer (score 1):

I think you should see chakra similar to heat. If it is 20 degrees celsius you dont see heat.
Now if its 40 degrees celsius you can see the air vibrating/moving.

First of, people with visual prowesses can see chakra.

> Although chakra is usually invisible, those with certain dōjutsu, like the Sharingan, Rinnegan or Byakugan, can see the colour of someone's chakra. Each person's chakra apparently has a different colour.

The second point comes closer to my heat theory

> It is also interesting to note the fact that sufficiently immense amounts of chakra are visible to the naked eye.

Here comes the intersting part " When does chakra count as immense ?"

We know that in naruto there is a system simalar to our blood veins, [the chakra pathway system](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Chakra_Pathway_System). Allong these paths there are special points called [Tenketsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tenketsu).

> Though ninja use chakra regularly, very few ninja possess any great control over their tenketsu. Even of jōnin, the vast majority are only capable of releasing a small amount of chakra through their hands or feet to increase the power of punches, jumps, or kicks

The Hyuga clan's main attack focus on closing those Tenketsu. The The Eight Trigrams Sixty-Four Palms closes sixty-four tenketsu.

> Though not explicitly stated, it is logical to say that the Hyūga clan (and Neji independently) calculated the exact tenketsu that would be required to shut down an opponent's combat ability.

With this information we can conclude that people whom can still function with 64 tenketsu shut are considerd above normal.

> Neji Hyūga was shocked that Naruto Uzumaki was still able to stand after being hit with Eight Trigrams Sixty-Four Palms as his body should have been in a virtually quadriplegic state.

We can also assume that the chakra a bijuu transmits to the user surpases the 64 tenketsu limiter, also the chakra from a bijuu is considerd more pure/powerfull then a normal chakra user

> The tailed beasts (尾獣, bijū) are the nine titanic behemoths within the Naruto series. They are living forms of chakra, sometimes referred to as "Chakra Monsters" giving them immense reserves of especially strong chakra that far outmatches most shinobi. The tailed beasts' chakra is coloured red

There are still some mystery's regarding chakra. But as we slowly find out more in the manga/anime a beter answer might pop up.